# How can I make a navigation bar that navigates between pages in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, navigation, navigationbar

I want to make a program that has a couple of categories on the top that you can navigate through. for instance: 'Home' 'Patients' 'Appointments' 'History'  etc..

Every category you click shows its own buttons and labels on the screen.

(Just like the categories you see when you go to the Properties of any file on the desktop:  'General' 'Sharing' 'Security' 'Previous Versions' ...)

How do I do that?

If I put all the buttons and labels on the screen and just change their .Visible from True/False based on what category I click, you can see the controls appear and disappear in runtime which is not the correct way to do this obviously.

Any suggestions? is there a Tool that I can use?

Sincerely,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: What you're looking for is a `TabControl`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant, but you should consider using the [MDI Application design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Basically it allows you to create a program in which multiple forms can appear, and each form has its own controls. Most of the time, these type of application use a menu bar, for an easy navigation throughout the program.